# Does objective-c have a utility package or library like Java's java.util?

Tags: java, objective-c, ios

Does objective-c have built in utility packages supporting things like List, HashTable, Tree, Date, etc? I come from a Java background so I'm trying to draw parallels to `java.util` to better understand.

Answer (score 2):

You may think you need a Tree, but just remember what you really want is a data structure with roughly the same O(n) algorithmic performance - read the details on guarantees NSArray gives you for storage and performance.

What you are looking for is then:

- NSArray (array sort of but also a tree)
- NSDictionary (Hash table)
- NSSet (unique hash table)
- NSDate along with NSDateFormatter

Comment: +1 please see my answer here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834299/why-is-there-no-queue-in-cocoa/10835245#10835245

Comment: Excellent, I was thinking of your very answer when I wrote the bit about NSArray

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa, not Objective-C, has the `Foundation` library which contains basic data types, including the ones you're asking about (except maybe Tree).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're working on iOS, so you can use Apple's NS classes. Take a look at the [developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/). It sounds like you'll be interested in the [data management section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Topics&topic=Data%20Management), and [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003641) and [NSCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003626).